# Custom CSS style rules apply only when added in style tag if Bootstrap CSS is linked

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am dealing with the above issue.

I use Bootstrap CSS to a custom layout I am working on, and of course I need to apply my own custom CSS style.

If I link the bootstrap.min.css and above that I link my style.css, my custom rules do not apply.

But, if I link bootstrap.min.css and above that I add my custom rules in a  tag, they work properly. I am using my own IDs and classes, and I have already checked if the file path are correct.

I am adding an example of both approaches I tried inside of the head tag on my HTML file:

This doesn't work

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“css/style.css“>
```

This works

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
 [custom css rules]
    .
    . 
    .
</style>
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have sample code for further clarification? From what I understand on your question, it depends on the ordering of the `<style>` tag which is expected since it'll process it sequentially.

Comment: You might be running into a CSS specificity issue: are you sure your selectors are sufficiently specific so that they can override bootstrap's stylesheet?

Comment: add style.css below bootstrap css, the second value will be taken by css, so try to write the overriding css below

Comment: @AashiqRathnadas that is how I linked the files but it didn't work :(

Comment: can you provide some sample custom css code you have given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `<link href="css/custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this solution! It worked! Can you please explain why reordering the link attributes changed the result?

Comment: You missed type = "text / css"

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the notice!